# Select... LIMIT.... Медленная работа на больших выборках. MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый день.
Есть запрос:

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.f1,
    t1.f2,
    t1.f3,
    t1.f4,
    t2.date,
    t3.f5,
    t2.f6,
    t2.f7 FROM (
    select 
        date,
        id,
        f7,
        f6,
        f8
    FROM t2            
    WHERE t2.date >= ? and t2.date <= ?
) as t2 INNER JOIN  t1 on t2.id = t1.f9 LEFT JOIN t3 on t2.f8=t3.id ORDER BY t2.date LIMIT 5499945,99999
```

Проблема в том что при больших значениях LIMIT OFFSET запрос выполнятся жутко долго. Что можно сделать как можно оптимизировать.?

Comment: убрать вложенный запрос? Также посмотреть EXPLAIN (может там индексов не хватает)

Comment: Если убрать вложенный запрос время обработки увиличивается на 50%

Comment: А что с id происходит во времени. Можно ли заменить limit на операции `> < ` с id. это могло бы дать большой прирост. По факту вы выбираете 5499945 лишних записей, сортируете и потом просто выбрасываете. Если бы id росли во времени и вы бы где то сохранили нижнюю планку необходимых id могли бы вообще не выбирать эти записи

Comment: Аналогично, если дата содержит время можно было бы где то хранить верхнюю планку времени и небольшой offset относительно начала данной секунды в поле даты. и поправить условие интервала дат

Comment: Расматривал такой вариант. Но к сожалению выборка должна быть отсортированна по дате (необходимое условие) а id могут быть задним числом (тоесть бОльший id на меньшую дату)

Answer (score 1):

Filesort, да на таких объёмах (судя по параметрам LIMIT), ну никак быстро не сделать. А с учётом того, что сортировка идёт по полю подзапроса, т.е. по неиндексированному набору данных - не вижу потенции оптимизации этого запроса в принципе.

Предлагаю рассмотреть вариант трансформации запроса в процедуру. В ней сделать выборку подзапроса в TEMPORARY TABLE ENGINE=Memory, проиндексировать, а уж потом получать итоговую выборку. Чем на большее число записей распадается подзапрос после связывания с другими таблицами, тем больше шанс поиметь профит... да, сам подзапрос (отбор во временную) тоже следует залимитировать, или во всяком случае постараться это сделать.